# UIWebView Background-Image: url('image.png') doesn't work?

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of Mobile Safari and create a StandardError.html file to display an image and some text about an error on webview when it fails to load.  I'm having trouble getting an image to show when using Background-Image: url('image.png') css, but not when doing it all in html using a div.  I'm not sure why one works and the other fails, any help would be greatly appreciated!

On a side note, any help with getting that image to center using html would be awesome!

Thanks!

Edit: HTML to center url:

```
<div name="backgroundImage"> <center> <img src="image.png"/> </center> </div>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code that you are using to position the elements.

Comment: It's centered on the screen vertically, but not horizontally.  I can post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample from an HTML page I'm loading in a webview it should work as a good guide to accomplish your task.  I'm using CSS to position my element, and loading it using HTML.  The css will center the image horizontally on a screen with a width of 320px (iphone width)

```
// in css block
#product { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative; 
    width: 320px;
}

in html block
<div id="container">
    <div id="product"><img src="products-product-in-library.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, it might just be my html skills, but I'm still unable to center it.  Any idea why setting the background-image: url("image.png") doesn't work?

Comment: First thing that would come to mind would be since you are defining the background of the div, but not perhaps the position, and the div may not be large enough to see the background at its current location.  Here's a link that may be helpful using the div background positioning method http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-position_pixel

Comment: Alright, well thank you for the link.  I'm still unsure of why the webview won't recognize files using just the css of background-image, but I'll figure out how to center the image using html one way or another.

Comment: Doesn't using <img src="something"/> inside of a div that defines the center working?

Comment: Yes, it does.  It's just figuring out how to center that image horizontally in the div which is difficult.  My question is also why background-image: url('image.png'); doesn't work when Apple uses it in the mobile safari application, and why it doesn't work now when it did work in the past (prior to iOS 5.0)

Comment: Seems that it was a formatting error on my part!  Your code did end up working correctly to center the image, and I was able to use background-image: url('image.png') correctly.  Thank you for all the help!